# Java – Finding minimum and maximum values in an array

Tags: java

I can't find my error here?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    class Code {
            public static void main (String[] args) {
                    Scanner a = new Scanner (System.in);
                    System.out.println("Please, Enter Array Size : ");
                    int size = a.nextInt();
                    double[] arr = new double[size];
                    System.out.println("Enter Array elements : ");
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                            arr[i] = a.nextDouble();
                    }
                    int max = arr[0];
                    int min = arr[0];
                    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
                            if (max < arr[i]) {
                                    max = arr[i];
                            }
                            if (min > arr[i]) {
                                    min = arr[i];
                            }
                    }
                    System.out.println("maximum is : " +max);
                    System.out.println("minimum is : " +min);
            }
    }
```

Comment: This is a pure programming question and has nothing to do with Unix or Linux. Please post programming questions to Stack Overflow instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are getting error because of different data types. The array you have defined is of double data type, but the `min` and `max` variables are of `int` type. So make them of `double` data type like:

```
double min,max;
```

If you want to keep `min` and `max` of `int` data type then you need to typecast the array element like:

```
min=(int)a[0];
```

but it is not recommended.

Comment: ohhooo!!! Thank you very much.
I did it on 'C', but there no error.
I shift few day's ago in java, & i have faced many small problem,which is getting bigger for me!
In that case i was thinking 'C' is better then 'java' :)